# React materialize Chips and icons

Tags: reactjs, materialize

I'm trying to set Tags using react materialize, and it seems like the Tag component won't transfer the "close" class to the icon, even after trying to set it manually.
Image from the html displayed:
[image]

The result:
[image]

and the tag is not clickable.

When i edit the html from the console, i get the Tag as it should be and it can e clicked:
[image]

My code is:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Row, Tag, Col, Chip } from 'react-materialize'
class CreatePost extends Component {
render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <form noValidate>
                    <Row>
                        <Col>
                            <Tag className="close">test tag</Tag>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

```html
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

JSON:

```js
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-materialize": "^2.6.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Try with Chip

So
Change

```
   <Tag className="close">test tag</Tag>
```

To

```
   <Chip className="close" close={true}>
       test tag
   </Chip>
```

Comment: I tried, it didn't work.
as a workaround i changed it to
<Chip >test tag
        <Icon className="close" onClick={this.removeTag}>close</Icon>
</Chip>
and it works, but i wonder why does it have to be manually

Comment: My answer should work as per their docs. I also don’t understand why